# AWS QuickSight Cohort(customers returning rate)

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am using AWS quickSight for anyltics.
I have a data set contains customer, orderDate, order
I want to create a cohort report showing the customer return rate. so assume in the first month I have 100 new customers, I need to show in the next months how many customers from the 100 is returning to use my service.

Example

|  | month 0 | month 1 | month 2 | month 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jul, 2022 | 200 | 50 | 20 | 29 |
| Aug, 2022 | 250 | 100 | 30 |  |
| Sep, 2022 | 300 | 70 |  |  |
| Oct, 2022 | 330 |  |  |  |

in the example above, in Jul I have 200 new customers, from the 200 customers in the next month 50 customers returned to use our service, then in the second month, 20 customers from the 200 customers return to use our service, and so on.

is this doable using AWS QuickSight, Please share your thoughts

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [How to Perform Cohort Analysis](https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/how-to-perform-cohort-analysis/233)

I think it will answer your question.